# How to add property to prop(ReactComponent)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-tsx

I wanna set properties (key/name) to props.answerComp/ 
Consider that props.answerComp = `<Radio>`

```
{answers.map((item,id)=> {

    setAnswers([...answers, props.answerComp]) // 1
    // setAnswers([...answers, <Radio name={props.questId} key={id + 1}/>]) // 2 LIKE THIS
})}
```

I tried *props.answerComp.key* but it doesn't work 
This is result of `console.log(props.answerComp)`
[image: result of console.log(props.answerComp)]

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the `Radio` element and extend it with props:

```
setAnswers(
    answers.map((item, id) => {
      return React.cloneElement(props.answerComp, { name: item.questId, key: id + 1 });
    })
  );
```

Or even add the key to only a wrapping React.Fragment:

```
      return <Fragment key={id + 1}>
                 {React.cloneElement(props.answerComp, { name: item.questId })}. 
             </Fragment>;
```

You'll need to pass the component prop as `answerComp={Radio}`.

Note that if the answers can be added, deleted or reordered then you should use a better key, `item.questId` for example, instead of the index.